# hardware keyboard and mouse sharing linux/windows to mac/windows with international support

Tags: linux, windows, macos, kvm-switch

I've a primary desktop pc with Linux/Windows on it and a secondary Mac mini with OS X and Windows, one monitor each.

I'd like to share keyboard and mouse from primary to secondary, have already tried Synergy but it currently lack international support, so on my Italian keyboard some main key, like the space bar, doesn't work correctly (already filled an issue long time ago).

Lately I've seen some promising hardware usb km switch device (try google for *2 port usb km switch*)  even with clipboard sharing support (wireless or with cable doesn't really matter to me) but any I've seen had some limitation, like only english layout keyboard support or partial support for some of the OS (Linux can't be used as server).

I'd like to know if someone is successfully using some hardware km switch with Linux/Windows as server and OS X/Windows as client, with international keyboard layout support (and obviously eventually what is this device).

(I tagged the question *kvm-switch* but would be *km-switch* which doesn't exist and I can't create)

Comment: Might this be something for you? http://www.keyboard-and-mouse-sharing.com/usb-switch.htm

Comment: Thank you @digorydoo, seems a nice product but 1. doesn't mention Linux support (which is the OS I'm using more) and 2. I've already experienced troubles with *software switcher* on some OS X multimedia application where keys events weren't handled by the system API, and I guess this is something that can happen in any OS (for instance [libOIS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wgois/))

Comment: I would suggest you to visit a nearby store and check with few available Bluetooth keyboards like the Logitech Bluetooth Easy-Switch Keyboard.

Comment: @GautamJose thanks, bluetooth may be an option, but 1. I'd like to hear from someone who's happily using it with all the three OS (the easy-switch seems to not support Linux too) 2. there's still the mouse question

Comment: yeah, my point was not to buy the easy switch, but visit a store and try out some Bluetooth combos. Reviews and specs may not come any where near hands on experience.

Comment: A purely mechanical KM switch should work with any keyboard and any OS. Clipboard sharing will naturally require drivers, so these sophisticated switches are not for you.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for your comment, interesting, do you know some working mechanical KM switch? For clipboard sharing there are already  software solution working over network on all three OS.

Comment: It has been many years since I used a mechanical KM/KVM. Search in Amazon for "km switch" and set Customer Review to 4-star and more, then read the comments and you cannot go wrong. You can also post questions that may be answered by users with experience of the product. In case of a mistake, the return policy of Amazon is excellent - just don't overdo it.

Comment: @GautamJose 's comment gave me an idea, apparently with Linux (I would use a raspberry)  is *relatively* easy to emulate a bt keyboard/mouse device (see [1](http://askubuntu.com/a/233848) and [2](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/emulate-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-the-raspberry-pi)), just need to figure out how to handle/trigger the *switch event*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a simple KVM and just not connect the video. This would cover your stated requirements except clipboard sharing. Which you already said could be done via some other software you found.

Something like this [IOGEAR](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817399032&Tpk=N82E16817399032) would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep in mind as last fallback option, may have also a point if I'll ever want or need to use only one monitor (a kvm with a key-combo switch would have two points), is that an analog VGA? ...

Comment: That is an analog VGA KVM. I use a 4 port one at work. I have 8 monitors, 4 computers, 1 keyboard and mouse and just `scroll lock X2` and get control of the next computer.

Comment: @Alex have u found the solution?

Comment: @Eugene I bought a KVM and I don't plug in the monitor, as suggested, it works for what I have to do with it. The only flaw is that the KVM I bought fails to power the Apple keyboard which probably consumes more than a standard keyboard. With the other pc keyboards I tried there were no problems.